# Weblogic admin startup issue

Tags: weblogic12c

Referring the oracle document i bind the server processes to a user ID (none).

"When Node Manager runs as an init.d service, the launched Managed Servers are owned by the root user. To start Managed Servers as non-root user, first use the Administration Console to enable the Post-Bind UID and Post-Bind GID attributes on the

> Domain > Environment > Machines > Configuration > General page

Then, restart Node Manager and the Administration Server before restarting the Managed Servers."

In the Administration Console, in the left pane, click on the Machines folder.
In the right pane, selected the Configure a New Unix Machine link.
Enabled Post-Bind UID and Post-Bind GID attributes

As per suggestion saved the settings and restated admin server. Upon restart I am getting below error in the admin.out.

```
<Jul 9, 2016 6:16:29 AM UTC> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000252>
<Cannot switch to the group "nobody".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setegid: no such group: 'nobody'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setegid: no such group: 'nobody'
at weblogic.platform.Unix.setEGroup0(Native Method)
at weblogic.platform.Unix.setEffectiveGroup(Unix.java:73)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SetUIDRendezvous.setEGroup(SetUIDRendezvous.java:159)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SetUIDRendezvous.makeUnPrivileged(SetUIDRendezvous.java:186)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SetUIDRendezvous.initialize(SetUIDRendezvous.java:87)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.BootService.start(BootService.java:75)
```

Comment: Could you please when did you got this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope your configuration file got corrupted. Please follow the below steps:

1. Take a backup of the config.xml file.
2. If your adminserver not starting then you could open config.xml file in the $DOMAIN_HOME/config. Search for 'nobody' word then update UID, GID as per your OS level user and group details.
3. Start your Admin server.

Update your end what happend.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Pavan,it is working after amending config.xml